# How do I remove the indent from an unordered list but not using CSS?

Tags: html

the code is below---I want to make the change in a few places, but not across the board.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div style="margin: 0px" >
      58% of the population is age 19 or younger (an estimated 520,000 children), compared with 36% of the broader population. 
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="margin: 0px">
      3% are age 65 or older, compared with 11% of the broader population. 
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The elements you've chosen come with default styles that must be overridden with CSS.  The only other option would be to use different elements.

Comment: When you say "I want to make the change in a few places" can you be more specific? Is it every 3rd item? Or every second item but only in the first 6 items? If you can be more specific that will really help - thanks!

Comment: Just add a `class` to the elements which you want to remove the indent and set the css like `.your_class {margin:0; padding:0 }`

Comment: You should use a class, there is no need to copy the CSS source when you could use a class to simplify it. Also, wouldn't you want this style on the `li` tags instead of the `div` tags? I would expect the margin to be on the `ul` or `li` tags, not the `div`s.